# want to write a scenario in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i am new in pinescript and i want to check that the second candle closing is below the high of the 1st candle or not how can i check that. Can someone please let me know how can i do that

I tried the below but not working

```
//@version=5
indicator("Gap Up and Close Below Daily High Checker", overlay=true)

// Input for percentage threshold for gap-up
gapThresholdPercent = input.float(1, title="Gap Threshold (%)", minval=0, maxval=10, step=0.1)

// Calculate the percentage change from the previous close to the current open
gapUpPercent = ((open - close[1]) / close[1]) * 100

// Check if the current open is a gap-up based on the threshold
isGapUp = gapUpPercent > gapThresholdPercent



higherClose = close >= open[1]
closeLower  = close[1] < close[2]


// Plotting shapes on the chart for visualization
bgcolor(isGapUp ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)


// Displaying information on the chart
plotshape(series=isGapUp, title="Gap Up", color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=higherClose, title="High", color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(series=closeLower, title="Low", color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
```

Comment: AI-generated code is inconsistent, buggy, and unreliable. Artificial Intelligence is very useful in many aspects, but it encodes Pinescript very poorly (for now...)

Consequently, TradingView and the PineCoders community have decided to [not provide support](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) to fix GPT-related code.

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Gap Up and Close Below Daily High Checker", overlay=true)

// Input for percentage threshold for gap-up
gapThresholdPercent = input.float(1, title="Gap Threshold (%)", minval=0maxval=10, step=0.1)
var bool isGapUp=na
var bool higherClose=na
var bool closeLower=na

if(barstate.isconfirmed)
    gapUpPercent = ((open - close[1]) / close[1]) * 100
    isGapUp:= gapUpPercent > gapThresholdPercent
    higherClose:= close > high[1]
    closeLower := close < low[1]

// Plotting shapes on the chart for visualization
bgcolor(isGapUp ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na)

// Displaying information on the chart
plotshape(series=isGapUp, title="Gap Up", color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(higherClose, title="High", color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(closeLower, title="Low", color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
```

Comment: Hi SRPV, its not working according to the requirement

Comment: Could you tell me second candle means previous candle? Or pls explain in image.. Il try to change code

Comment: Hi SRPV, I need indication on 2nd candle. for example if the market gapdown and the next candle(2nd candle) did not close the the below of the 1st candle low then indicate the second candle...but only and only need to indicate the 2nd candle not the 3rd,4th,5th and so on....

Comment: Hi SRPV Is there any update?

Comment: Hi Sahil. You have added gapup logic in your code. Do you need for gapup or gapdown? You need to check this logic for  2nd candle in a day or for 1st opening candle in a day after gapup or gapdown (based on previous day last candle) ?

Comment: I have security concern. Is there any way I can privately share my emailId? I am new to this platform.

Comment: Hi Sahil. Yes I saw your message. please check your chat room once